Blender 4.2 Preferences not saving
I am trying to save these two Preferences so that they persist and load with each start-up of Blender: Preferences > Animation > F-Curves > Unselected Opacity (from 0.250 to 0.125) and Only Show Selected F-Curve Keyframes (from unchecked to checked). I made the changes, then clicked File > Defaults > Save Startup File > Overwrite. But when I close and reopen Blender, these Preferences are reset to the original default (0.250 and unchecked, respectively). Is there something else I need to do to save these Preferences?
I do have Auto-Save Preferences checked in the hamburger menu at the bottom left.

The described procedure saves a startup file, not preferences. Preferences are saved from the hamburger menu at the bottom of the Preferences Window under Save Preference if you don't have Auto Save enabled.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I upvoted your comment because that's what I would have said too, but here it seems to be a bug or some (to me) incomprehensible functionality... see my comment below Brian's answer.

Agree, that is why I posted it as a comment and not an answer. There seems to be something else at play here, either something unforeseen, or there is a bug in either the auto save feature or in detecting those changes to preferences. Sounds like a bug report worth making.

So, it's confirmed that this is a bug. https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/127678

Curiously, even though I do have Auto-Save Preferences selected, the solution was still to click Save Preferences in the hamburger menu at the bottom left. Thanks to Duarte Farrajota Ramos for pointing me there.

Although I agree with @DuarteFarrajotaRamos comment, I can confirm this issue. Usually I have Auto Save enabled and for almost all changes I made this worked for me (as far as I remember), but now when I tried this it actually did not save the changes automatically. Even weirder: if I also change something else, like unchecking "Show Warning" in the Keyframes menu above the F-Curve menu, then the F-Curve menu changes are saved automatically. So this answer seems to solve your problem, but all in all it seems there is a bug in the Auto Save function of the Preferences...
